# Promise resolve action is triggered late in ReactJS app

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, promise, es6-promise

I am writing a simple app that needs to get some weather data from an API . endpoint.
I am very new to React, so this is probably me not understanding something about how to work with promises in React.

Here is my code:

```
var React = require('react');

var Weather = React.createClass({
   getInitialState: function() {
     console.log('GetInitialState', 'info');
      return {
        foo : 1,
        weatherConditions : "No weather data"
      };  
   },

   update: function() {
     console.log('Updating State', 'primary');
     let self = this;
     function httpRequestWeather(url) {
       return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
          var weatherRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
          weatherRequest.open("GET", url, true);
          weatherRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if ( this.status === 200) {
                console.log("request finished and response is ready");
                console.log(this.response);
                // only returns when I post code here
                self.setState({
                    weatherConditions: this.response
                 });

                resolve(this.response);
            } else{
                reject(new Error("no weather data"));
            }
          };
        weatherRequest.send();
      });
     }
  httpRequestWeather("www.weatherendpoint.con/json").then(function(responseText){
    let text = JSON.parse(responseText);
    //never gets triggered
    self.setState({
        weatherConditions: "Hi"
     });
  }).catch(function(){
     //always triggered
    self.setState({
        weatherConditions: "Buy"
     });
});

  this.setState({foo: 2});
},

 render: function() {
   console.log('Render', 'success');
   let condition = this.state.weatherConditions;
   return (
    <div>
        <span>{condition} </span>
        <span>{this.state.foo} </span>
    </div>
    )
  },

 componentWillMount: function() {
  console.log('ComponentWillMount', 'warning');
  this.update();
 },

 componentDidMount: function() {
   console.log('ComponentDidMount', 'warning');
   this.update();

 },

shouldComponentUpdate: function() {
  console.log('ShouldComponentUpdate', 'info');
  return true;
}

 });

module.exports = Weather;
```

Basically, the problem is that in this function I have to trigger 
self.setState({weatherConditions: this.response});

```
function httpRequestWeather(url) {
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      var weatherRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
      weatherRequest.open("GET", url, true);
      weatherRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if ( this.status === 200) {
            console.log("request finished and response is ready");
            console.log(this.response);
            // only returns when I post code here
            self.setState({
                weatherConditions: this.response
             });

            resolve(this.response);
        } else{
            reject(new Error("no weather data"));
        }
      };
    weatherRequest.send();
  });
 }
```

If I try to set state on promise resolve, I always get unresolved.

```
httpRequestWeather("www.weatherendpoint.con/json").then(function(responseText){
let text = JSON.parse(responseText);
    //never gets triggered
    self.setState({
       weatherConditions: "Hi"
    });
  }).catch(function(){
    //always triggered
    self.setState({
      weatherConditions: "Buy"
    });
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get an error while doing the request. You should check the error first, see why you get it and based on that set the `state` appropriately for the error flow.

```
httpRequestWeather("www.weatherendpoint.con/json")
 .then(function(responseText){
    let text = JSON.parse(responseText);
    self.setState({
       weatherConditions: "Hi"
    });
  }).catch(function(err){
    console.log('Error on request:', err);
    self.setState({
      error: err
    });
 });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That helped! I am doing this right now and got yet another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42885936/unexpected-end-of-json-input-on-promise-resolve .   Do you mind helping out?

Comment: @margarita just an FYI that `React.createClass` is being deprecated in the next major release. They are planning on pulling it out to a separate package so it can still be used after `16.0.0` is released. You can use ES6 `class` to build _stateful_ components. For more information:

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/8854

https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/9232

https://github.com/reactjs/react-codemod#explanation-of-the-new-es2015-class-transform-with-property-initializers

Comment: Thank you! I will take a look!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call `self.setState(...)` under both success and error conditions, then the following pattern could be useful :

```
asyncRequest()
.then(function(data) {
    return { /* properties */ }; // state object (success)
}, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    return { /* properties */ }; // state object (something suitable to describe an error)
})
.then(self.setState);
```

So here you might write :

```
httpRequestWeather() // pass url if necessary
.then(function(weatherData) { // make sure `httpRequestWeather()` delivers data, not a JSON string.
    return {
        'weatherConditions': weatherData,
        'error': null
    };
}, function(err) {
    console.log('Error on request:', err); // optional
    return {
        'weatherConditions': 'unknown',
        'error': err
    }
})
.then(self.setState);
```

The particular properties above are just my idea of what might be useful, and are open to adaptation according to what `self.setState` (and/or `self.render`) expects. For example, the `error` property may be unnecessary.